# How does velocity get computed in EKF INS systems?

Tags: imu, ekf

In GPS IMU nav systems Velocity and angular position are not explicitly measured states yet at each timestep it's necessary in order to integrate IMU information.

I'm curious how is this dealt with?

Is it computed via linear interpolation or is something else done? Sames goes for EKF based SLAM systems.

Answer (score 2):

*Any* Kalman filter uses the covariance matrix (usually denoted $\mathbf P$ in the engineering literature) to keep track of the coupling between states.  With this coupling, and state measurements, the filter can deduce how the hidden state estimates need to be updated.

As a very over-simplified example, if you have a system where your measurement matrix $\mathbf H = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and the covariance matrix $$\mathbf P = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}, $$then the covariance matrix is saying that $x_2$ is *exactly equal* to $-x_1$ -- so as soon as you measure $x_1$, you know $x_2$ absolutely.

That's not how it works in practice (in fact, that $\mathbf P$ matrix would cause serious numerical problems in the filter), but the gist of it is that each time you take a measurement on a state that is coupled to another, you can update *that* state, as well as the one you measured directly.

In an integrated IMU - position system things are lots more complicated, because the system is time varying, based on how the vehicle is moving.  So there's not sufficient information to fully deduce orientation until there's been a change in acceleration, and the nav solution will degrade if the acceleration becomes constant.

**However**, in such a system the observation model will be along the lines of
$$ \mathbf H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf I & \mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0 & \cdots
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where the embedded identity matrix picks the position out of the state.  Because the position is dependent on the velocity and orientation, even if the starting covariance between the velocity and position, and the orientation and position are both zero, the first update step will introduce this covariance.

Comment: So would the observation model be a matrix consisting of the identity for the position and then 0s for the orientation and velocities? I don't understand how this will then update the velocity indirectly hmm.